# Argument of type '{ name: string; id: null; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'User'

Tags: angular, angular-datatables

I am making angular app using in memory web api. When I was trying to make `addUser()`function, this is the error I am getting at `createUser(data)`:

> Argument of type '{ name: string; id: null; }' is not assignable to
> parameter of type 'User'.   Types of property 'id' are incompatible.
> Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2345)

user-list.components.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from 'src/app/users/users.model';
import { UserService } from 'src/app/users/user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-list',
  templateUrl: './user-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-list.component.css']
})
export class UserListComponent implements OnInit {
  user = {
    name: '',
    id: null
  }

  edit = true;
  add = false;
  users!: User[];

  constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getUsers()
  }

  private getUsers(){
    this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(users => this.users = users)
  }

  addUser(){
    const data = {
      name: this.user.name,
      id: this.user.id
    };
    this.userService.createUser(data).subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response)
      this.getUsers();
    })
  }
}
```

user.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from './users.model';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, retry } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {
  
  private usersUrl = 'api/users/';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.http.get<User[]>(this.usersUrl).pipe(
      retry(2),
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.error(error);
        return throwError(error);
      })
    );
  }

  createUser(user: User): Observable<User> {
    user.id === null;
    return this.http.post<User>(this.usersUrl, user).pipe(
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.error(error);
        return throwError(error);
      })
    )
  }

  editUser(user: User): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.put(this.usersUrl + user.id, user);
  }

  deleteUser(id: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.delete(this.usersUrl + id);
  }
}
```

Comment: user shoul be `user = {name: '', id: 0  }` <--see that is 0, not null

Comment: It looks like you have `strictNullChecks` set to `true`, meaning you can't make parameters null like that. Does that value ever really need to be null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happen due to **typescript version 2.1 or later**, Please check your tsconfig.json file & search for **strictNullChecks**, you will see it's value is true.

I Believe that in your User Model, the parameter id has type **number**, but inside your component you created a default user object, with default values, inside that object the id parameter has null value,

Due to this null value, it's throw such error, I will suggest you that please update your default user object of component with type User Model, after updating, your code will be look like below

```
user: User = {
  name: '',
  id: 0
}
```

Now If you assign null to **id paramter**, the IDE or Code Editor itself show you error, similar to this

```
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'number'
```